# Elastic Beanstalk not running correct PHP Version

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Can someone please help me, I don't understand what is going on.

I just set up a working environment and the image I chose for the machine was PHP 7.2. When I try to deploy to the environment I am getting an error that the PHP version I am running (7.0.33) does not satisfy a minimum requirement of a plugin.

Why, when the config said that I am running PHP 7.2 on the server, do I see that I am indeed running 7.0.33 on the environment?

Anyone?

Comment: Hey, did you get an answer to this eventually - I am having the same issue after pushing upgrade command.

Comment: Same issue here. Any Solution to this?